# How to restore CoreBluetooth's CentralManager state on OSX? Or: Why is CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey unavailable?

Tags: xcode, macos, core-bluetooth

My OSX 10.10 application shall restore the CoreBluetooth `CentralManager` state using the `centralManager:willRestore` delegate method.

Therefore I use the `CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey` dictionary key to restore the bluetooth peripherals. But it doesn't compile due to the error

> CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey is unavailable

The symbol is defined only for iOS 7+ as:

```
CB_EXTERN NSString * const CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 7_0);
```

This said, the `NS_AVAILABLE` annotation makes that symbol unavailable on OSX.

[The CBCentralManagerDelegate's documentation unfortunately says nothing about how to restore the manager's state](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBCentralManagerDelegate/centralManager:willRestoreState:). The only thing it mentions is

> `- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central willRestoreState:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)dict`
>
> `dict:` A dictionary containing information about the central manager that was preserved by the system at the time the app was terminated. **For the available keys to this dictionary, see Central Manager State Restoration Options.**

But there isn't such a dictionary description. [It however exists for iOS.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Central_Manager_State_Restoration_Options)

So, how do I successfully restore the `CentralManager` on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS, apps do not get terminated by the operating system for memory reasons the way they do get terminated on iOS.

When iOS then restores a terminated app, it will also restore the previously connected peripherals to give the iOS app a chance to continue talking to these peripherals.

This said, there's no need on macOS to restore such peripheral connections.